# Web API is getting NULL value as "NULL" from angular?

Tags: c#, angular

I am having an webAPI file & a angular file from which the null value is passing to the web API .
while passing the null value it is reflecting as "NULL".
my API controller  TS file is as follows

```
getOfficeOrganizationalRoles(OfficeSelected,gbobranchname): ng.IHttpPromise<SelectItem[]> {
        //return this.http.get(this.apiEndpoints.baseUrl + this.apiEndpoints.getOfficeOrganizationalRoles + "?officeIds=" + OfficeSelected + "&gbobranch=" + gbobranchname);
        return this.http.get(this.apiEndpoints.baseUrl + this.apiEndpoints.getOfficeOrganizationalRoles + "?officeIds=" + OfficeSelected);

    };
```

how can i get the null value with the "" removed .i need the value for both OfficeIds & gbobranch.

Comment: did you properly debug your api result? how is this looking like?

Comment: @sree can you explain a bit more and some error message

Comment: yes , i have looked it . the API result is "NULL" .

Comment: i have a issuepopcontroller , in that the method which is hitting is 
 this.userService.getOfficeOrganizationalRoles(this.officeIds,this.gbobranch)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.scope.roles = response.data;
                })

this a ts file ,here the value is comming as NULL (no issues),but when it is coming to API call the above mentioned code. there it is having the value as "NULL"

Comment: I need to pass the parms ,but the value should remain as it is either NULL or any sting or integer.here what happening is the NULL value coming through 

this.userService.getOfficeOrganizationalRoles(this.officeIds,this.gbobranch) .then((response) => { this.scope.roles = response.data; })

is getting converted into "NULL". when it is hitting the API contoller.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this so you won't have to pass params if they are null

```
getOfficeOrganizationalRoles(OfficeSelected, gbobranchname): ng.IHttpPromise<SelectItem[]> {
        const params: any = {};
        if (OfficeSelected) {
            params.officeIds = OfficeSelected;
        }

        if (gbobranchname) {
            params.gbobranch = gbobranchname;
        }

        return this.httpClient.get(this.apiEndpoints.baseUrl + this.apiEndpoints.getOfficeOrganizationalRoles, { params });
    };
```

Comment: this is not working it is not hitting the API file( i.e the method which is above )